# Linking Raphael.js to a js without the use of html file

Tags: javascript, node.js, raphael

I have a requirement where in i need to use Raphael.js in a js file which is to be executed on a server using node.
Tried using the import keyword to import Raphael into the script but import 
 keyword is undefined when i run it on node.
And also searched for answers on stack overflow but most of the answers are related creating script element but in my case i dont have an html.
Things which i have tried does not give the desires result.Any help or suggestions.

Comment: I'm rather curious what you'd need to draw server side that wouldn't be more appropriate client side.

Comment: Need to create pdf and save it on server which would be passed on to the client. Pdf creation and all is working just need a way to link the said library

Comment: Would https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-raphael be of any use ?

Comment: I have a script already written in raphael.js just need a way to link the library to my job script

Comment: But I will consider your suggestion and try out